# Work with Value from PropertyValueFactory in TableView - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecell

In my JavaFx project I have a scene with a few views. For the footer of the window I have a class extending from TableView:

```
public class FooterView extends TableView<Area> implements ViewTemplate {...}
```

This displays a Table with some data from a .csv-file.

When it comes to assigning the value of the specific presentationmodel property to the cells I do it like that:

```
TableColumn<Area,Double> powerColumn = new TableColumn<>("Power Overview");
powerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("powerPerArea"));

this.setItems(filePM.getAreas()); //filePm is my filehandler
this.getColumns().addAll(powerColumn, other_columns);
```

`getAreas()` looks like this:

```
public List<Area> readCantonsFromFile() {
        try (Stream<String> stream = getStreamOfLines(AREA_FILE_NAME)) {
            return stream.skip(1)
                    .map(l -> new Area(l.split(DELIMITER, 12)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
}
```

In the constructor of `Area` i set the properties. One of the properties is the mentioned `powerPerArea`

```
private final DoubleProperty powerPerArea = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
...
public void setPowerPerCanton(double powerPerCanton) {
    this.powerPerCanton.set(powerPerCanton);
}
```

**My question:** Is there a way to change the value in the FooterView before the value is displayed? I tried something like this:

```
powerColumn.setCellValueFactory(Math.round(new PropertyValueFactory<>("powerPerArea")));
```

But it seems that I mixed up DoubleProperty, Double and ObservableDouble. Can I even modify the value in here?

The problem: I can not round the value in the setter because I add a double value in a loop through this function:

```
public void addPowerPerArea(double power){
    double sum = getPowerPerCanton() + power;
    setPowerPerCanton(sum);
}
```

And rounding the value in here would give me a wrong result. (rounding not precise enough). I need to do it in the end when all sums are added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `cellValueFactory` to determine *which data* are displayed in the cells: in this case the data returned by your `PropertyValueFactory` is the actual `double` value returned from `powerPerAreaProperty().get()`, which is exactly what you want.

If you want to control *how* the data are displayed, you should use a `cellFactory`. So to display the data in a particular format, including limiting the number of decimal places, you can do:

```
powerColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Area, Double>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double power, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(power, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(String.format("%.0f", power.doubleValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

The point here is that you should not modify the data based on how you want to display it; the purpose of having both `cellValueFactory` and `cellFactory` is to separate the *display* of the data from the actual data itself.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to returning custom cells from a `cellFactory` would be to use a custom `cellValueFactory` to return the property formatted as string:

```
TableColumn<Area, String> powerColumn = new TableColumn<>("Power Overview");
powerColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().powerPerAreaProperty().asString(""%.0f""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this. You could:

use the `setCellFactory` method and in the updateItem method you format it. Should look something like this, haven't tested

```
powerColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<Area, Double>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(Math.round(item), empty);
        }
    };
});
```

OR: You could make another property of your `Area` class that is bound to the existing `powerOfArea` property but returns the value rounded. I am sure that is somehow possible, you could just override some functions of a `readOnlyDoubleProperty` but there should be a better way. Maybe via `DoubleBindings`.

Comment: This does not work. `TableCell` does not display anything unless you override `updateItem` accordingly...

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure it's really a good idea to modify the *item* that the cell is displaying. After calling `super.updateItem(Math.round(item), empty));`, the cell's `getItem()` method will return the rounded value, which is not really the expected result here. The `item` should be the data value from the model.

Comment: @fabian Curious why is that the case? I do call the superclass. Is the default cell not a TableCell but some internal subclass? There is no LabelTableCell or something like that is there?

Comment: The `TableCell` used by default is a anonymus inner class of `TableColumn` (returned by `TableColumn.  DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY`). `TableCell` does not implement any change of the cells look itself since all `TableCell`s need to call `super.updateItem` from `updateItem` and if some default behaviour was implemented there, it would make the code less performant and also wouldn't allow programmers to call `super.updateItem` at the end of the overriding method...

Comment: @fabian thanks for the explanation. Curious did you just upvote James_D comment? Because you kind of violate it with your own answer, since you use a different value than what is provided by the model.

Comment: I did even though James's comment is not 100% precise. According to the contract the value assigned to the `TableCell.item` property is the one that the `ObservableValue` returned by the `cellValueFactory` contains.